# after call ajax from jquery menu action view mvc c# is not rendering _layout

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I built a dynamic jquery menu c# (VS2013) with bootstrap 3.0 that works fine on load but when I cliked on link item menu by using calling ajax the cursor pass in action view of controller but doesn't render it. I tried using Ajax.Actionlink and this menu simple clear after clicked on link menu item.

This is my _layout, and I build menuClever:

```
<body>
    <div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left">
        <div class="scrollable">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="menuClever">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="canvas">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="false" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="container fluid">
            <div class="container body-content" id="funcaoContainer">
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                <p></p>
                <p>@RenderBody()</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

And this is my jquery Menu:

```
    $.fn.menuClever = function (atributos, opcoes) {
        var defaults = {
           propriedades: {}
        };

          var r = {
            registros: atributos
        };
        var p = {
            registros: []
        };

        if (opcoes) {
            $.extend(defaults, opcoes);
            var titulo = '';
            titulo += '<h4>';
            titulo += defaults.tituloMenu;
            titulo += '</h4>';
            $('#menuClever').prepend(titulo);
            var menuItem = '';
            var idFuncionalidadeAnterior = 0;
            var nivelAnterior = 0;
            var qtdItems = 0;
            if (r.registros.length > 0) {
                idFuncionalidadeAnterior = r.registros[0]['IdFuncionalidadeAnterior'];
                nivelAnterior = r.registros[0]["Nivel"];
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < r.registros.length; i++) {
                if (r.registros[i]['Nivel'] > nivelAnterior) {
                    menuItem += '<ul>';
                }
                else
                    if (r.registros[i]['Nivel'] < nivelAnterior) {
                        menuItem += '</ul> </li> </ul> ';
                        if (r.registros[i]['IdTipoFuncionalidade'] == 1) {
                            menuItem += '<ul>';
                        }
                    }
                if (r.registros[i]['IdTipoFuncionalidade'] == 1) {
                    menuItem += '<li><a href="#">' + r.registros[i]['Funcionalidade'] + '<span class="glyphicon arrow"></span></a>';
                }
                else {
                    if (r.registros[i]['Parametros'] != null) {
                        menuItem += '<li><a class="funcaoClever" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#funcaoContainer" href="' +
                            r.registros[i]['Url'] + r.registros[i]['Parametros'] + '">' + r.registros[i]['Funcionalidade'] + '</a></li>';
                    }
                    else {
                        menuItem += '<li><a class="funcaoClever" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#funcaoContainer" href="' +
                            r.registros[i]['Url'] + '">' + r.registros[i]['Funcionalidade'] + '</a></li>';
                    }
                }
                nivelAnterior = r.registros[i]['Nivel'];
                idFuncionalidadeAnterior = r.registros[i]['IdFuncionalidadeAnterior'];
            }
            menuItem += '</ul>';
            $('#menuClever').append(menuItem);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I made a test with this ajax too:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: a_href,
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function (result) {
        alert('Oh no: ' + result.responseText)
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but I think you're using Ajax wrong. An Ajax request is mostly used to refresh a part of the page instead of the whole page. When you refresh the whole page I suggest to use a normal request (easier to implement). In MVC an Ajax request returns a `PartialView` (that is without the _layout) and you JavaScript code should handle the returned html (i.e. put it in a `<div>` or something).

Comment: Thank you !! PartialView solve my problem !